# How can i create a class with Arrays in NodeJS

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have a some Class files which I use to generate my Request Document to make a request to my Backend. The main Class holds an Array as well as that class holds another Array. Below is what my class looks like

```
class RsaInitial{
    constructor(clientId, subjectName, subjectCredentials, context){
        this.clientId = clientId;
        this.subjectName = subjectName;
        this.subjectCredentials = subjectCredentials;
        this.context = context;
    }
}
class RsaContext{
    constructor(authnAttemptId, messageId, inResponseTo ){
        this.authnAttemptId = authnAttemptId
        this.messageId = messageId
        this.inResponseTo = inResponseTo
    }
}
class RsaSubjectCredentials{
    constructor(methodId, collectedInputs ){
        this.methodId = methodId
        this.collectedInputs = collectedInputs
    }
}
class RsaCollectedInputs{
    constructor(name, value ){
        this.name = name
        this.value = value
    }
}
module.exports = {
  RsaInitial,
  RsaContext,
  RsaCollectedInputs,
  RsaSubjectCredentials
}
```

So when I want to create new instance I also have to declare that the item is an empty Array. Is there a way in the class file to declare a variable an empty array when i initiate a object based on that class or is the only way while i create the new object ?

This is how i do it for now..

```
  let MyRSA = new rsa.RsaInitial
    let MyRSACont = new rsa.RsaContext
    let MyRSASubject = new rsa.RsaSubjectCredentials
    let MyRSACollected = new rsa.RsaCollectedInputs

    MyRSACollected.name = 'testUser'
    MyRSACollected.value = '123456'

    MyRSASubject.collectedInputs = []
    MyRSASubject.methodId = 'SECURID'
    MyRSASubject.collectedInputs.push(MyRSACollected)

    MyRSACont.messageId =  uuidv4()
    MyRSACont.authnAttemptId = ''
    MyRSACont.inResponseTo = ''

    MyRSA.subjectCredentials = []
    MyRSA.clientId = 'crmApi'
    MyRSA.subjectName = 'test'
    MyRSA.subjectCredentials.push(MyRSASubject)
    MyRSA.context = MyRSACont
```

Comment: In the constructor?

Comment: Set it in the constructor? Unrelated, but it's unclear why you have ctors that take the values you're setting manually instead of just calling the ctors with those values (and you're missing `()` on your `new` expressions).

Comment: fun fact: thats why constructor were invented.

Comment: How would I set in the constructor  ? Yes i know i forgot the () on new but it acts the same with or without..

Comment: @MisterniceGuy: You *are* setting it in the constructor. But you aren't passing the parameters it wants. See my answer.

Comment: Check my answer :)

Answer (score 0):

You're calling `new` wrong. `new` should have the following syntax:

```js
new ClassName      // no params
new ClassName()    // no params
new ClassName(...) // params
```

Your constructor expects parameters you aren't passing, so they all become undefined.

Here's a fixed version:

```js
    let MyRSACont = new rsa.RsaContext(uuidv4(), '', '')
    let MyRSACollected = new rsa.RsaCollectedInputs('testUser', '123456')
    let MyRSASubject = new rsa.RsaSubjectCredentials([MyRSACollected], 'SECURID')
    let MyRSA = new rsa.RsaInitial([MyRSASubject], 'crmApi', 'test', MyRSACont)
```

Comment: using your sample i get this error UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: TypeError: Cannot read property 'push' of undefined

Answer (score 0):

Let's say:

```
class Car {
  constructor(name, year) {
    this.name = name;
    this.year = year;
  }
}
```

So, **Expression** should be: `let myCar1 = new Car("Ford", 2014);`

---

Your code should be like below:

```
let MyRSACont = new rsa.RsaContext(uuidv4(), '', '')
let MyRSACollected = new rsa.RsaCollectedInputs('testUser', 123456)
let MyRSASubject = new rsa.RsaSubjectCredentials('SECURID', [MyRSACollected])
let MyRSA = new rsa.RsaInitial('crmApi', 'test', [MyRSASubject], [MyRSACont])
```

Happy coding :)

Comment: Sorry but this doesnt solve anything since passing MyRSASubject will create an object not an Object in the Array

Comment: @MisterniceGuy then use `[MyRSASubject]`...?

Answer (score 0):

Actually the solution was simpler then I thought. All i had to do was to change my calls to this

```
class RsaInitial{
    constructor(clientId, subjectName, subjectCredentials, context){
        this.clientId = clientId;
        this.subjectName = subjectName;
        this.subjectCredentials = [];
        this.context = context;
    }
```

that way it was initialized as an empty array and i can push objects into it without init the array first.